# Why are my action creators being called in the wrong order when using thunk?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I was experimenting with redux-thunk and action creators and noticed some strange behavior that I don't understand. When I call the action creator functions they don't get called in the order I want them to. This is my App.js component

```
class App extends Component {

  handleSave = () => {
    this.props.postData({
      name:this.props.activity,
      type_name: this.props.type
    })
    this.props.fetchList()
    this.props.fetchData()
  }

  handleClick = () => {
    this.props.fetchData()
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchData()
    this.props.fetchList()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <Nav />
          <Route exact path='/' render={props => <Home {...props} clickProp={this.handleClick} saveProp={this.handleSave}/>} />
          <Route exact path='/activities' render={props => <ListContainer {...props} numItems={this.props.list.length} listProp={this.props.list}/>} />
        </Router>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    activity: state.activity,
    type: state.type,
    list: state.list
  }
}

const actions = {fetchData, fetchList, postData}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(App);
```

When I click on a button in the Home child component the handleSave function gets called which is then supposed to post an item on to my list and then fetch the updated list so that it can be shown in my list. When I do this, this.props.fetchList() gets called first even though it is the second function being called. I have placed a console.log(action) inside my reducer and this is what is printed.

```
{type: "FETCH_LIST", payload: Array(86)}
{type: "POST_DATA", payload: {…}}
{type: "FETCH_DATA", payload: {…}}
```

The only way that I can get the FETCH_LIST to happen after the POST_DATA is if I call fetch_data() a second time like so

```
  handleSave = () => {
    // something weird going on here
    this.props.fetchList()
    this.props.postData({
      name:this.props.activity,
      type_name: this.props.type
    })
    this.props.fetchList()
    this.props.fetchData()
  }
```

I really want to be able to get my code to work without having to call the same function twice if it is possible. Finally, this is what my action creators look like.

```
export default function fetchData() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const url = 'http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/'
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(activity => { dispatch({type: "FETCH_DATA", payload: activity})})
  }
}

export default function fetchList() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3001/activities'
    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(list => { dispatch({type: "FETCH_LIST", payload: list})})
  }
}

export default function postData(activity) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:3001/activities'
    const config = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({activity})
    }

    fetch(url, config)
      .then(r => r.json())
      .then(activity => {dispatch({type: "POST_DATA", payload: activity})})
  }
}
```

My only guess is that this is happening because these actions are asynchronous. So I have also tried to change the order in which these functions are called and no matter what FETCH_LIST always happens before POST_DATA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert those action creators to `async` versions and then you can await them so they execute in order.

https://medium.com/@gaurav5430/async-await-with-redux-thunk-fff59d7be093

For example on your `fetchData`

```
function fetchData() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    const url = 'http://www.boredapi.com/api/activity/'

    try{
      const res = await fetch(url)
      const activity = await res.json();
      dispatch({type: "FETCH_DATA", payload: activity})
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Once they are `async` you can await them in your `handleSave` (once you convert it to `async`) This will ensure they get called in order.

```
handleSave = async () => {
    await this.props.postData({
      name:this.props.activity,
      type_name: this.props.type
    })
    await this.props.fetchList()
    await this.props.fetchData()
  }
```

Comment: Original actions would work as well, just need to return the promise: `return fetch(url)` and `return fetch(url, config)`